# Django under supervisord?

Tags: python, django, supervisord

django project is running under supervisord, when i try to edit the html templates, nothing changes in the web site, should I restart the supervisord or is there other easier way to make changes to the project?

Comment: try to clear browser cache or check in incognito window.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool are the django views dependant of browser cache?

Comment: you talked about  html templates that's why is said because you are editing HTML templates.

Comment: Supervisors is not suitable for development and editing the templates is not suitable for production. Couldn't put please describe your development process?

Comment: @KlausD. a django project started by supervisord, the only thing i wanna do is to make changes to the templates, is it the supervisor caching data or django itself??? cause i dont know how supervisor works internally

Comment: @tooez in my experience you need to restart gunicorn (if you are using that)